# Get latest commits on another branch git (without checking it out)

Tags: git

Say I am on branch `dev` and I want to view latest commits on master without changing to it.

I simply want to do *some command* and then be able to see commits on master with for instance `git log master` or `gitk master`.

What is the *some command*?

How do i get latest commits from master remote without checking out master and then doing `git pull`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `git fetch`.

(Avoid `git pull`, which is just `git fetch` followed by a second Git command.  The second command defaults to `git merge`, though you can tell Git to use `git rebase` instead.)

The `fetch` command is what actually brings over commits.  They are then name-able through your *remote-tracking branch names*, such as `origin/master`.  These are the names *your* Git uses to remember what it saw on some other (remote) Git, the last time it talked with that other Git.  Your `git fetch` sees that they have a `master`, so copies its commits to your repository and uses the name `origin/master` to remember them.

Once you have the commits, `git log origin/master` or `gitk origin/master` (or `gitk --all`, or many other variants) will let you view them.

One of my favorite aliases is `incoming` / `lin`:

```
[alias]
    incoming = log --oneline ..@{u}
    lin = log ..@{u}
```

With this alias, `git incoming` shows the commits that are on the current branch's *upstream*.  For instance, the upstream of `master` is usually `origin/master`, so this shows commits that are on `origin/master` that are not on `master`.  The `--oneline` squishes them down to one line of subject each.  Usually I want to see more, so the shorter `lin` (Log INcoming) shows them without `--oneline`.

Answer (score 7):

No matter what you will first have to run `git fetch`. This will not make changes to the local copies of your branches.  It will `fetch` the changes from the current `remote` which can be referenced in virtual branches like `origin/master`.

Then you can view changes on the any branch by using the ref `origin/master` with out making changes on `master`

The command you want is:

`git log origin/master`

Comment: Well, by default `git fetch` fetches only from the *current* remote. Add `--all` to fetch from all remotes, or use `git remote update`, which defaults to ... well, a complicated arrangement that in turn defaults to "all remotes". Most people only have one remote, named `origin`, though.

Comment: thank you @torek I was unaware of that. I have updated my answer

Comment: And in case it's not obvious, if you already have the commits or it's not a remote branch you want to look at just `git log <branch-name>` will show you the local commits.

Answer (score 0):

> How do i get latest commits from master remote without checking out master and then doing git pull?

you can do the following:

```
# update internal git repository data 
git fetch

# now add any desired commit from any branch to your current branch (any)
git cherry-pick <sha1>
```

If you just want to view the log and not adding any commit to your branch simply use this:

```
git fetch --all --prune
git log --all --oneline --decorate --graph
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To see all commits of all the branches you can run

```
# Updates remote branches for all repositories
git remote update
# Shows all commits of all branches including remote ones
git log --all --decorate
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working fine:

```
git fetch origin master:master
```

Comment: The `master:master` refspec here means "fast-forward my local `master` based on their `master`, if possible".  There's nothing wrong with this, but note that the fast-forward operation will fail if you have a commit they do not, in which case you need to merge or rebase your commit onto theirs.  (Be careful, though, that you are not *on* your `master` when you do this. Well, it will tell you: `fatal: Refusing to fetch into current branch refs/heads/master of non-bare repository`)

Comment: you can also fetch all as i showed yo in my answer. `git fetch --all --prune`.  `fetch` only update the internal pack files while pull does a `fetch + merge`

Comment: Thanks guys for clarifying what master:master does, maybe it is not allways an good idea to do this, it might cause unnecessary confusion :)

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers stated, `git fetch` is the way to go.

After that, I recommend using `gitk` to view the commits of other branches, either with `gitk <branchname>` for a view of a specific branch or `gitk --all` for a view of all branches and their respective commits.